# nicematrix - Cdots not going all the way through blocks

Tags: matrices, nicematrix

I would like to draw a dotted line all the way through my matrix, but it looks like the use of \Blocks prevents the line from reaching the ends of the matrix. See output below.

```
Mat_\B(p) = J_{\dim F} = \begin{pNiceMatrix}[last-col]
        \Block[borders={right, bottom}]{3-3}{}1 & & & \Block[borders={bottom}]{3-1}{0}\\
        & \Ddots[line-style=standard] & \\
        \Cdots[line-style=dashed]& & 1 & \Cdots[line-style=dashed] & \leftarrow \dim F\\
        \Block[borders={right}]{1-3}{0} & & & 0
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the minimal working example? I see only a snippet code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the keys `shorten-start` and `shorten-end` with negative values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\def\B{\mathcal{B}}
\newcolumntype{I}{!{\vrule}}

\begin{document}

$\operatorname{Mat}_\B(p) = J_{\dim F} = 
\begin{pNiceArray}[last-col]{cccIc}
 1 &        & \\
   & \Ddots & & 0 \\
 \Cdots[line-style=dashed,shorten-start=-2.2mm] & & 1 & \Cdots[line-style=dashed,shorten-end=-2mm] & \leftarrow \dim F \\
\Hline
 & & & 0
\end{pNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]